# Edit view not filling the values

Tags: admin-on-rest

The `Edit` view is not filling the fields as expected, and I cannot figure out why. The REST endpoint returns the data, and the same works fine during `Create`, but it seems like `Edit` is not using the values (it's the same `source`). Weird as just the `name` input is filled, but that may be coming from the `List` view.

Tried with the sample `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` and it works, so I'm guessing my server is wrong somehow.

Any ideas?

Here is how my server is responding:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/api/facility/O42f026921e0f551819b4a5413ed67487
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 28 Jan 2018 21:26:34 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin

accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
authorization:R887b9a67f1d71a69a3ac7d39b65853c6
Connection:keep-alive
content-type:application/json
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

And here is my edit view:

```
export const FacilityEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit title={<FacilityName />} {...props}>
        <TabbedForm>
            <FormTab label="resources.tabs.summary">
                <ReferenceInput source="companyId" label='resources.company.name' reference="company" allowEmpty>
                    <AutocompleteInput optionText={choice => `${choice.name}`} />
                </ReferenceInput>
                <TextInput source="name" label='resources.facility.fields.name' />
                <EmailField source="createdBy" label='resources.fields.createdBy' />
                <DateField source="createdAt" label='resources.fields.createdAt' />
            </FormTab>
            <FormTab label="resources.tabs.address">
                <NumberInput source="address.zipCode" label='resources.address.fields.zipCode' />
                <TextInput source="address.address1" label='resources.address.fields.address1' />
            </FormTab>
        </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: You pasted the response's headers but not the actual response (JSON object).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. On the `List` view I had a `id`, but on the `Edit` view I had a `itemId`, which was causing the problem.